# Different return types from protocol method

Tags: swift

I would like to have a protocol that defines some methods and properties. However, property types and method return types may vary between the different classes that conform to said protocol. For example: `A.getContent()` may return a value of type `String`, but `B.getContent()` may return a value of type `Int`. In my example below, I used the type `Any`. Is this possible in Swift or is this a totally wrong approach? Maybe with generics?

```
protocol Content {
    func getContent() -> any
}

class A: Content {
    func getContent() -> String {
        return "Im a String"
    }
}

class B: Content {
    func getContent() -> Int {
        return 1234
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the [associated types section in the Swift programming language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID189) :)

Comment: Maybe with generics.

Answer (score 9):

I think you are looking about Generics in Protocol.
You can associate a type dynamically with `associatedtype`, for example

```
protocol Content{
    associatedtype T
    func getContent()-> T
}

class A: Content {
    func getContent() -> String {
       return "Hello World"
    }
}

class B: Content {
    func getContent() -> Int {
        return 42
    }
}

A().getContent() //"Hello World"
B().getContent() //42
```

If you look at this example when you put the Type after the function in the class sun of Content, the protocol Content will be this one type

**Update**

I am putting another example using "swiftly" syntax instead of traditional `getContent`.

```
protocol Content{
    associatedtype T
    var content:T { get }
}

class A: Content {
    var content:String{
        return "Hello World"
    }
}

class B: Content {
    var content:Int{
        return 42
    }
}

A().content //"Hello World"
B().content //42
```

Comment: Looking good! Problem is that i cant work with it then. For example in another class i try `func addContent(content: Content) { ... }` but Xcode is showing: `Protocol 'Content' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

Comment: Same for just trying to create an array: `var contents = [Content]()`

Comment: @Mick that's because a `Content` with an associated type `String` is a completely different type than `Content` with an associated type `Int`. There's no real way around that, they just aren't compatible.

Comment: @Mick Depending on what you want to achieve, you have several options available to you. For function inputs, you can introduce a generic placeholder for the individual function (i.e `func addContent<T: Content >(_ content:T) {...}`), for class properties or methods, you can introduce a generic placeholder to the class itself. If you need to talk about heterogenous `Content` types (i.e 'any thing that conforms to `Content`'), you'll want to look at [type erasures](http://robnapier.net/erasure).

Comment: @Hamish is there a way i can make implementation to return [String] and another one Int in the above example???

Comment: @ThatlazyiOSGuy웃 Sure, the associated type can be satisfied by any type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use generics and meta-types:

```
protocol Content {
    func getContent<T>(ofType: T.Type) -> T?
}

class A: Content {
    func getContent<T>(ofType: T.Type) -> T? {
        return "Im a String" as? T ?? nil
    }
}

class B: Content {
    func getContent<T>(ofType: T.Type) -> T? {
        return 1234 as? T ?? nil
    }
}

let aClass = A()
let aValue = aClass.getContent(ofType: String.self) // "Im a String"

let bClass = B()
let bValue = bClass.getContent(ofType: Int.self)    // 1234
```